# Is there a way to represent date hole in chartjs time series?

Tags: laravel, chart.js

I have a data collection in PHP / Laravel that has 30 min timestep.

So, I am supposed to have a collection like:

```
40 => array:2 [▼
    "time" => "2018-11-29T19:30:00.000000Z"
    "delta" => "5052"
  ]
  41 => array:2 [▼
    "time" => "2018-11-29T20:00:00.000000Z"
    "delta" => "3691"
  ]
  42 => array:2 [▼
    "time" => "2018-11-29T20:30:00.000000Z"
    "delta" => "2348"
  ],
 ...
```

Now, in my collection, it appears that I have a "hole", missing data. So I have a gap in my collection:

```
  46 => array:2 [▼
    "time" => "2018-11-29T22:30:00.000000Z"
    "delta" => "528"
  ]
  47 => array:2 [▼
    "time" => "2018-11-29T23:00:00.000000Z"
    "delta" => "932"
  ]
  48 => array:2 [▼
    "time" => "2018-12-03T23:30:00.000000Z"
    "delta" => "709"
  ]
  49 => array:2 [▼
    "time" => "2018-12-04T00:00:00.000000Z"
    "delta" => "753"
  ]
  50 => array:2 [▼
    "time" => "2018-12-04T00:30:00.000000Z"
    "delta" => "649"
  ]
```

Here you can see I have missing data between `2018-11-29T23:00:00.000000Z` and  `2018-12-03T23:30:00.000000Z`

In ChartJS, I can see no "hole", because the 4 missing days are not represented in graph. Is there a way to visualise missing data in ChartJS ?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up solving this problem directly with query. As I use TimescaleDB, I can use function: `time_bucket_gapfill`

So, here is my query:

```
$measures = \App\Models\Measure::where('meter_id', $meter->prm)
            ->whereBetween('time', [(clone($missingData->date_ini))->subDays(1), (clone($missingData->date_end))->addDays(1)])
            ->select([
                DB::raw("time_bucket_gapfill('30 minutes', time) AS pt30m"),
                DB::raw('sum(delta) as delta'),

            ])
            ->groupBy('pt30m')
            ->orderBy('pt30m')
            ->get()->map(function ($measure) {
                if ($measure->delta == null) $measure->delta = 0;
                return $measure;
            });
```

I'm still interested in learning how to do it from chartJS.

Comment: The proper way would be to define a time axis: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/time.html